# Php ternary operator to if

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have looked through the PHP manual about ternary operators and I found it hard to understand.

How can I convert this ternary operator to an `if` statment or edit so it will do the following code below. Instead of `echo`ing I want the code to run a method depending on whether or not the use has logged in,

```
echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is effectively:

```
if ($openid->validate()) {
    $temp = $openid->identity . ' has ';
} else {
    $temp = 'has not ';
}

echo 'User ' . $temp . 'logged in.';
```

It sounds like what you want to do is:

```
if ($openid->validate()) {
    handleLoggedInFunction();
} else {
    handleNotLoggedInFunction();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be (regarding what he really want to do), it's probably just a dynamic way to print out a label wether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I took "Instead of echo out i want the code to run a method instead of echo user has/has not logged in" to mean he wanted to execute some other method in each case, and not actually print anything out.  I could be misinterpreting that though.

Comment: Thx. I think this is what i was looking for. Also thx to @Zar

Comment: Would have given 1+ if i had more repuation ;)

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be:

```
echo 'User ';

if($openid->validate()) {
   echo $openid->identity . ' has ';
} else {
   echo 'has not '
} 
echo 'logged in.';
```

There are, however, cleaner ways to write code that does the same thing (look at the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = true;
$value ? runFunction() : (echo "has not logged in");
```

Extrapolating:

```
$openid->identity() ? loggedInFunction() : notLoggedInFunction();
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I didn't use his variables, that's about it.

Comment: Sorry, never mind. I didn't read this part `or edit so it will do the following`. I though he was only looking for an `if` statement. -1 removed. :)